# Ubuntu `systemctl service` stops after some time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, services, systemd-journald

Ubuntu `systemctl service` does not work after some records. After 10000 records `service status` is running but data cannot sync. After `service restart` it's working but again after 10000 records it's stopped.

## Service Output

[image]

## Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Synchronization log from syslog
[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
Type=forking
TimeoutSec=0
GuessMainPID=yes
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/dv2/synclog_app/multiple.bash "/home/dv2/synclog_app" >/dev/null
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## multiple.bash code

```
PROJECT_DIR=$1
SYSLOG_DIR="/var/log/syslog"
/bin/bash ${PROJECT_DIR}/log_monitor.bash ${PROJECT_DIR} ${SYSLOG_DIR}
```

## log_monitor.bash

```
PROJECT_DIR=$1
LOG_DIR=$2
tail -fn0 ${LOG_DIR} | while read line ; do php ${PROJECT_DIR}/php_script_log_read.php "${line}";  done
```

Please Help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in `journalctl -u <servicename>` ?

Comment: Nothing only start log.